# Does the Hausdorff dimension characterise CAT(0) spaces having some bilipschitz balls?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

It is well-known that the Hausdorff dimension is invariant under bi-Lipschitz mappings. I would be interested in a specific converse of this invariance. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two CAT(0) spaces having the same Hausdorff dimension.

In addition, we assume that the metric curvature of $X$ and $Y$ is bounded from below. More precisely, we assume that we have a $\kappa<0$ such that the metric curvature is at least $\kappa$. In order to explain this, we need some preparation. We denote by $M_\kappa$ the hyperbolic plane where the metric is scaled by $1/\sqrt{-\kappa}$. For a triple of points $x,y,z \in X$ we may pick points $x',y',z'\in M_\kappa$ where $d_X(x,y)=d_{M_\kappa}(x,y)$, $d_X(x,z) = d_{M_\kappa}(x,z)$ and $d_X(y,z)=d_{M_\kappa}(y,z)$. For two points $a,b$ we denote by $[a,b]$ a geodesic connecting $a$ and $b$. For a point $u\in [x,y]$ we call a point $u'\in [x',y']$ a comparison point if $d_X(x,u)=d_{M_\kappa}(x',u')$ and $d_X(u,y)=d_{M_\kappa}(u,y)$. Now the condition we have is that for every triple $x,y,z\in X$ and all $u\in[x,y]$ and $v\in [x,z]$, we have
$$
d_X(u,v) \geq d_{M_\kappa}(u',v')
$$
where $u'\in[x',y']$ and $v'\in [x',z']$ are comparison points for $u$ and $v$, respectively.

Can we find two open balls $B_1 \subset X$ and $B_2\subset Y$ and a bi-Lipschitz surjective mapping $f\colon B_1\to B_2$?

Without the lower bound on the curvature, this is not possible as pointed out by [YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14094/ycor) and [user142382](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14094/ycor). One reason is that there are compact $\mathbb{R}$-trees of arbitrary large Hausdorff dimension - see e.g.

> P. D. Andreev and V. N. Berestovskiĭ: Dimensions of ℝ-trees and self-similar fractal spaces of nonpositive curvature. Siberian Advances in Mathematics 17: 79–90(2007). DOI: [10.3103/S1055134407020010](https://doi.org/10.3103/S1055134407020010)

Comment: Take the real line vs a tree in which the set of branching points is dense?

Comment: Or the 2-dimensional plane vs. a compact tree of Hausdorff dimension 2.

Comment: @YCor and user142382 Thank you very much for these comments. In the situation I am actually interested in this question, we also have a lower bound on the metric curvature. Does this help?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with any purely metric notion of having a lower bound on the metric curvature.

Comment: Hi Christian. It can sometimes frustrate people on this website if you ask a question, get a counterexample, impose more conditions, and repeat this cycle. If you have a precise question about the case in which the curvature is bounded in two directions, I'd suggest you try to ask it explicitly, either by editing this question or starting a new one.

Comment: @user142382 Thank you! I guess, I will pose a new question so that both of you can post an answer to this one which I can upvote and accept one of them (e.g. the first one).

Comment: @YCor If you post your counterexample as an answer I can accept it. I will ask a new question with both curvature conditions.

Comment: @Christian This is not worth an answer. I'd prefer you edit the question; you might just mention that examples as a remark.

Comment: Are you familiar with Nikolaev's theorem on Alexandrov spaces with 2-sided curvature bounds?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I was not familiar with this theorem. It looks like this is what I need.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106508/existence-of-a-riemannian-metric-inducing-a-given-distance/673742#673742).

Comment: By the way I'm not that confident with my answer (I wasn't aware that a compact tree can have Hausdorff dimension 2, and don't know whether there's a nonempty compact tree in which the set of branching points is dense). It's maybe very easy, but I'm not familiar enough with Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @YCor Thank you. I removed the counterexamples for now since I did not check them in all details. I will add them after checking the details.

Comment: One can take a Cantor set in R^3, say, of Hausdorff dimension 2 and build a compact (abstract) tree whose set of leaves is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the Cantor set. (Branchings correspond to stages of the Cantor set construction.) There are details to check. Confession: I am not an expert on CAT(0), but I assume a compact (geodesic) tree will be CAT(0). I believe that Moishe Kohan's answer really takes care of the two-sided case.

Comment: For sure, any tree (with the geodesic metric) is CAT(0).